# How can I start an OSGI bundle at runtime?

Tags: osgi, equinox, eclipse-rap

I need to wait to start a bundle during the execution of another bundle, is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean: Starting up order of bundles.

As when starting an OSGi application, how can I make sure that lower level services provided by other bundles, are available for higher level services (/ for other bundles). Then you should read into Dynamic Services.

There are a few ways to solve this issue (as it has changed in the different version of OSGi). In case you are new to OSGi and *Dynamic Service*, the most logical solution is probably *Declarative Services*, but at least you should also read about *Service Activator Toolkit*, as it also has it own advantages & disadvantages.

There is a nice online [Chapter 6, Dynamic Services](http://equinoxosgi.org/OSGi%20and%20Equinox%20-%20Ch06.pdf), which exactly describes this issue and what solutions there are to solve it (at least 3 solutions are described).

In general I can recommend the book [OSGi and Equinox](http://equinoxosgi.org/), for anyone wanting to learn about / apply OSGi (Equinox).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in different ways. First, you might have a look at the *start* method of the Bundle interface class. With it, you can start a particular bundle. You also might have a look at Declarative Services or the Start Level Specification.

As a start you should read section 4.4.5 (Starting Bundles) of the OSGi core spec (available at [www.osgi.org](http://www.osgi.org) for free).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `BundleContext.install()`? (`BundleContext` is passed in the activator start and stop methods)